# .scrollTop() only returning 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window, scrolltop

For some reason my $(window).scrollTop() is always returning 0. This was my initial code, and the scroll function wasn't even being called which seems strange, and might have something to do with it.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

I then changed the code and the scroll function is now being called, but the console is only logging 0 despite scrolling down the page.:

```
$('body#main-page').scroll(function(){
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

I think the fact that $(window).scroll(function(){}) wasn't even being called might have something to do with it?

I've also tried this, but no luck

```
console.log($('body#main-page').scrollTop());
```

Any suggestions, or advice on how to debug the problem?

Comment: Your code: http://jsbin.com/xusoset/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: It should return correct value, maybe you scrolling not `body` element? Could you provide live example of your code?

Comment: Can we help more or would you like us to explain more? Could you solve your problem? If you found [an answer usefull please upvote it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Your first code should work.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
p{
  height:4000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Tall paragraph to force BODY scrollbars</p>
```

---

It will **not work** only if another element has `overflow-y: scroll;` or similar (`overflow:auto;` etc)

ISSUE:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

#wrapper{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
#wrapper p{
  height:4000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Tall paragraph to force #wrapper scrollbars</p>
</div>
```

Scroll the above and see **nothing appears in console**!
Cause  `window` is not scrolling and 2: `window` has no changes on scrollTop value.

scrollTop can only be `>0` if an overflow **scrollable** element's `scrollHeight` is bigger that it's `offsetHeight` (has scrollbars).

Answer (score 0):

## Understanding scrollTop

From the [scrollTop docs](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/): `The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view  ... if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.`

So if you want to get a value other than zero

- the element must be scrollable
- inside this element the scrollbars must be in a non-zero position

In this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNaRpG?editors=1111) given this html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Scroll to </h1>
  <div id="a">some div</div>
  <a id="link" href="#l">click this link</a>
</div>
```

and this css

```
#wrapper{ overflow-y: scroll;
  width:400px; height:200px;
}
```

the `div id="wrapper"` is scrollable because of the css used. If you now scroll down inside `div#wrapper` and click on `#link` the scroll-bar position for wrapper is calculated using

```
var w = $("#wrapper");
var a = $("#link");
a.click(
  function(){
    a.text("scrollTop:" + w.scrollTop());  
  }  
);
```

So you have to make sure that both conditions for `scrollTop()` are met to get a value other than zero

- element must be scrollable (here `div#wrapper`)
- element must be in a scrolled state (happens only if you scrolled inside #wrapper)

You may [take a look at this fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGPXvp?editors=0001) and play around with it.

## Regarding your questions

#### Is the `scroll` function fired

To address your statement `the scroll function wasn't even being called` this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wo7Sd5gyiTDx3w7PV2zU?p=preview) contains code similar to yours

```
<style>
  .page{ height: 1200px;}
  p { height: 200px; border: 1px solid green;}
</style>

<div class="page">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>The scroll postion is:<i></i></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

and this javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var i = $("i");
  i.text($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

As you can see in the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wo7Sd5gyiTDx3w7PV2zU?p=preview) the code works as soon as you scroll. So to be able to help you better your full code is needed to see if and why it does not work.

#### `scrollTop` returns zero

You wrote `that the console is only logging 0 despite scrolling down the page`. The cause could be that your selector `$('body#main-page')` matches an element that is not scrollable. Without your actual code we can only speculate.